# python accessing the value of the raw_input as parameter

Tags: python, python-2.x, raw-input

Here is the example of the problem i am having it gives a duplicate of what i have entered for raw_input how do i access the value of raw_input and use it as a parameter of the function any one can help? i tried many times to amend it but didn't see any light of it i kind of know that the code must have treated the value as string but because i am new to python i don't have the necessary knowledge to solve it and it would be appreciated to have a full detailed how to.
Inculcate me :)

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return nights*140

a=raw_input("please enter number")
print hotel_cost(a)
```

thank you to all that contribute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string, you should convert it to an integer using `int()`:

```
a = int(raw_input("please enter number: "))
```

**Example:**

```
>>> "12"*10             # This is what your code is doing
'12121212121212121212'

>>> int("12")*10        # Expected output
120
```

Comment: thanks man i was suspecting this :) thank you for point it out

Answer (score 0):

[`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) will return a string so you have to do the convertion yourself. Or you can use [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) in 2.x. It equals `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.

```
a=int(raw_input("please enter number"))
```